# How to get the value from a Bundle to another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I have problem of getting value of bundle to another fragment my code is working but getting the different data from `SQLite` `Database` for Example I log in my account after logging in diffrent data from other account is display in my Profile.class if someone can show me how to get the value from a bundle to another `Fragment` class

This is what I have in my Login.class

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                DocProfile fragment = new Profile();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Name", c.getString(1));
                bundle.putString("Age", c.getString(2));
                bundle.putString("Gender", c.getString(3));
                bundle.putString("Address", c.getString(4));
                bundle.putString("Email", c.getString(5));
                bundle.putString("Contact", c.getString(6));
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
```

In my Profile.class to get the value from bundle but getting different user data

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Name"))
        name = args.getString("Name");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Age"))
        age = args.getString("Age");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Gender"))
        gender = args.getString("Gender");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Address"))
        address = args.getString("Address");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Email"))
        email = args.getString("Email");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Contact"))
        contact = args.getString("Contact");
```

Comment: did you use `getArgument()` ?

Comment: yes I have updated my question look what I did

Comment: what is the result of values?

Comment: different data from other accounts

Comment: debug your code, post value of your cursor ( c(1) , c(2) , ... c(6) ) and values on `args`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey when you try to get value from cursor try like this

i think problem is index number which you pass in `c.getString(int)`

```
bundle.putString("Name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("your_column_name")));
```

and rest of as @Sanket Kachhela guide you do like this

**Suggestion**

when you are get cursor value in loop use this

```
bundle.putString("Name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("your_column_name")));
```

like

```
 int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex("your_column_name");
 bundle.putString("Name", c.getString(columnIndex));
```

because

in loop finding column index every time is time consuming task this affect in app performance  while column index not change every time so find it once and use every time in loop

Comment: why in `int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("your_column_name");` you use `cursor` and in the next line you use `c` ?

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake you  have taken c as cursor variable and i have taken cursor as variable

Answer (score 2):

Use getArgument()

```
public class Test extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            String str = bundle.getString("YOUR_KEY");
        }

        }
```

Comment: I tried this but still I'm getting different user data

Comment: may I ask how to debug c.getString(1) ? srry new in programming

Comment: @user3766257 you can use `Log` like: `Log.d("c.getString(1)" , c.getString(1));` or you can use debug mode and see value on `c`

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

String name = bundle.getString("Name");
```

or

```
String name = bundle.getString("Name","yourdefaultvaluehere");
```

when bundle has no key named "name " it will take default value specified

Comment: I'm getting error on `defaultValue` can you explain why sir ? I'm kind of new in programming

Comment: when there is no such key it will take default value

Comment: but its asking me to create a local variable `defaultValue`

Comment: you can give direct value there or you can have reference for that defalut value by creating a local variable

Comment: if you ae getting some other data then the problem is with your cursor

move the cursor position accordingly

Comment: still getting different user data